# Wordpress widget missing after update to 4.3

Tags: wordpress, widget

Hello to all who want to help me with this (maybe) simple question. After wordpress is updated to 4.3 im missing my custom widget. This is the code that worked before. Still see my widget in the backend but its not showing on the front.

Whats do i have to change to get it working again in 4.3?

```
class Toast_Baan_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(

            // base ID of the widget
            'toast_baan_widget',

            // name of the widget
            __('Baanstatus Pro', 'broekploder' ),

            // widget options
            array (
                'description' => __( 'Baanstatus widget die de setting haalt vanuit de baanstatus opties', 'broekploder' )
            )
        );
    }

    function form( $instance ) {

        // markup for form ?>
       <p>Deze widget toont de baanstatus gegevens die zijn ingevuld bij de baanstatus optie</p>

    <?php
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {    

    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        // widget options

        echo $before_widget;  

        // WIDGET CODE GOES HERE
        query_posts(
            array( 
            'post_type' => 'baanstatus',
            'showposts' => 1 
        ));
        if (have_posts()) : 
            echo "";
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <h4 class="widget-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <p class="h-no-margin-bottom">Caddiemaster: <span class="h-link-color"><?php echo rwmb_meta( 'toast_bs_caddiemaster' ); ?></span></p>
                <p class="h-no-margin-top h-no-margin-bottom">Baanstatus: <span class="h-link-color"><?php echo rwmb_meta( 'toast_bs_baanstatus' ); ?></span></p>
                <p class="h-no-margin-top">Handicarts: <span class="h-link-color"><?php echo rwmb_meta( 'toast_bs_handicarts' ); ?></span></p>
                <p><span class="h-underline">Baanbezetting</span>: <?php echo rwmb_meta( 'toast_bs_baanbezetting' ); ?></p>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile;
            echo "";
        endif; 
        wp_reset_query();
        echo '<iframe id="widget-frame" class="h-center-block" src="http://www.weeronline.nl/Go/ExternalWidgetsNew/TwoDaysCity?gid=4057952&activityType=6&sizeType=1&temperatureScale=Celsius&defaultSettings=False" width="255" height="145" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: none;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>';

        echo $after_widget;
    }
}

function toast_register_wheather_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Toast_Baan_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'toast_register_wheather_widget' );
```

Hope someone can help put me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No not yet. Really has to do with the update to 4.3. When i search on a solution i read i have to use __construct. But already doing that

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in 4.3 that affects widgets with an empty $instance.  It is fixed in 4.31.  I was able to temporarily fix my custom widgets by modifying **wp-includes\widgets.php** line 319:

Change

```
if ( isset( $instances[ $this->number ] ) ) {
```

to:

```
if ( array_key_exists( $this->number, $instances ) ) {
```

I did not have to make any changes to the Update or _construct functions.

More information: [Reference # 33442](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33442)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with this.

```
class Toast_Baan_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(

            // base ID of the widget
            'toast_baan_widget',

            // name of the widget
            __('Baanstatus Pro', 'broekploder' ),

            // widget options
            array (
                'description' => __( 'Baanstatus widget die de setting haalt vanuit de baanstatus opties', 'broekploder' )
            )
        );
        add_action('widgets_init', array($this, 'widgets_init'));
    }

    function form( $instance ) {

        // markup for form ?>
       <p>Deze widget toont de baanstatus gegevens die zijn ingevuld bij de baanstatus optie</p>

    <?php
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        return $instance;
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        // widget options

        echo $before_widget;  

        // WIDGET CODE GOES HERE
        query_posts(
            array( 
            'post_type' => 'baanstatus',
            'showposts' => 1 
        ));
        if (have_posts()) : 
            echo "";
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <h4 class="widget-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <p class="h-no-margin-bottom">Caddiemaster: <span class="h-link-color"><?php echo rwmb_meta( 'toast_bs_caddiemaster' ); ?></span></p>
                <p class="h-no-margin-top h-no-margin-bottom">Baanstatus: <span class="h-link-color"><?php echo rwmb_meta( 'toast_bs_baanstatus' ); ?></span></p>
                <p class="h-no-margin-top">Handicarts: <span class="h-link-color"><?php echo rwmb_meta( 'toast_bs_handicarts' ); ?></span></p>
                <p><span class="h-underline">Baanbezetting</span>: <?php echo rwmb_meta( 'toast_bs_baanbezetting' ); ?></p>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile;
            echo "";
        endif; 
        wp_reset_query();
        echo '<iframe id="widget-frame" class="h-center-block" src="http://www.weeronline.nl/Go/ExternalWidgetsNew/TwoDaysCity?gid=4057952&activityType=6&sizeType=1&temperatureScale=Celsius&defaultSettings=False" width="255" height="145" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: none;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>';

        echo $after_widget;
    }
}

function toast_register_wheather_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Toast_Baan_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'toast_register_wheather_widget' );
```

Comment: Thanx for your help but it's not working. Tried this before.